How to attach CANCEL callback to the axios request promise so saga can handle it in TypeScript?
I want to attach CANCEL callback to the promise so saga can handle it.
My code:
import { CANCEL } from 'redux-saga';

cancellableCall = <T = any, E = ApiError>(
    options: AxiosRequestConfig,
    validationTemplate?: TemplateType,
  ): Promise<APIResponse<T, E>> => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    const request = this.call<T, E>(
      {
        ...options,
        signal: controller.signal,
      },
      validationTemplate,
    ) as Promise<APIResponse<T, E>>;

    request[CANCEL] = () => controller.abort();
    return request;
  };

But on this part of code request[CANCEL]
I have next TS warning:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Promise<APIResponse<T, E>>'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Promise<APIResponse<T, E>>'.ts(7053)
What I'm doing wrong?

So the solution is simple: just extend request type with adding [CANCEL: string] property:
export interface CancellablePromise<T = any, E = ApiError> extends Promise<APIResponse<T, E>> {
  [CANCEL: typeof CANCEL]: () => void;
}

